# error CS0103: The name does not exist in the current context (Debugger)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My debugger in VS2015 Update 2 is skipping variables

```
var god = DataContext.Calendars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Description == CalendarName);
if (god == null) return false;
```

if giving the following error when I try to debug it

> error CS0103: The name 'god' does not exist in the current context

I can see the code hitting my sql server.

[image: What it looks like in visual studio]

Comment: Have you read this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8zbaa6f.aspx

Comment: Yes, but that would be if the error was real and not an issue with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this was many years ago, but I just had the same issue.

You probably figured it out by now, but in case anyone else has this behaviour:

- Make sure you are actually in `debug` mode and didn't accidentally switch to `Release`
  [image: List item]